# Omit all the results even if one row has a different value

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I have a sample database:

```
Var1    Var2    Status
=========================
A1      SG1     Completed
A2      SG2     Completed
A2      SG1     Progress
```

Statuses can be as many as 10 different statuses.

I want to pull all the records only when all the rows' Status is 'Completed'. Meaning in this case no rows will be pulled. Only if all rows = 'Completed' then only it will pull the entire database.

How can I achieve this in lowest time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Var1, Var2, Status
from MyTable
where not exists (select 1 from MyTable where Status != 'Completed')
```

[See SQLFiddle for demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f90b/1)

Comment: Thank you so much! Was stuck at this for a long time!! Thanks again! Works perfect. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the unseemingly dumb question. A newbie, so learning! Thanks again.